# Using Jacoco4sbt with Play 2.2.x with alternate conf file

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, jacoco

I'm trying to get Jacoco4sbt running with Play Framework 2.2.1. I can get the tests to run with Jacoco, but they fail because they don't run with my alternate config. i.e.:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = jacoco_settings)
.settings(
 javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
 , parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
)
```

As the Jacoco4sbt documentation clearly states from their wiki:

> One caveat though: As you may have noticed, this plugin works in its own configuration, which is based on the test configuration. So, any settings you would normally define in the test configuration, you have to also define in the jacoco configuration for the plugin to work as expected.

Source: https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/wiki

So then the question is how do I pass the -Dconfig.file= JVM arg into Jacoco to run? Without it ultimately my tests wont run properly as I'm using the test config file to load a different global class and db connection.

Answer (score 3):

The solution of Nicolas did not work for me (Play 2.2.2). It gives me syntax errors. Here is my solution :

```
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt._
import JacocoPlugin._

// Other settings

testOptions in jacoco.Config += Tests.Setup( () => System.setProperty("config.file", "conf/application.test.conf") )

parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
```

Answer (score 1):

The caveat concerning the specific configuration can be solved by setting appropriate values on `jacoco.Config` (the specific configuration) in addition to `Test` (the default configuration).

The Play Framework configures a few options in `Test` (notably `fork` and `parallelExecution`) so theoritically you would just need to copy the proper configuration to `jacoco.Config`:

```
// WARNING: this does not work
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(jacoco_settings)
  .settings(Seq(
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf",
    javaOptions in jacoco.Config  += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf",
    fork in jacoco.Config := true,
    parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
  )
```

But as stated on [Issue #14](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/jacoco4sbt/issue/14/plugin-fails-if-test-is-forked-in-sbt) and [Issue #21](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/jacoco4sbt/issue/21/set-different-config-file-for-play#comment-7270168) on BitBucket, you cannot run tests in forked mode when running JaCoCo. `javaOptions` is only used in forked mode, so you cannot simply configure `javaOptions in jacoco.Config`.

Alternatives include setting the property when calling the test command:

```
play -Dconfig.file=conf/application-test.conf jacoco:cover
```

Or setting the property during tests setup:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(jacoco_settings)
  .settings(Seq(
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf",
    testOptions in jacoco.Config <+= Tests.Setup({ () => 
      System.setProperty("config.file", "webapp/conf/application.conf")
    }),
    parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
  )
```

Of course you can always run tests in non-forked mode without JaCoCo too:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(jacoco_settings)
  .settings(Seq(
    testOptions in Test <+= Tests.Setup({ () => 
      System.setProperty("config.file", "webapp/conf/application.conf")
    }),
    fork in Test := false,
    testOptions in jacoco.Config <+= Tests.Setup({ () => 
      System.setProperty("config.file", "webapp/conf/application.conf")
    }),
    parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false
  )
```